# Using .format() to print a string that does not exceed a defined number of spaces and is centered?

Tags: python, string.format

So Im trying to do three things here.
1. Get the print statement below to be 16 spaces long 
2. Cut off the extra = signs on eiter side of the name that cause it to be longer than 16.
3. Center the text so an equal amount of = signs are either side of the name

This is my attempt...

```
import random

name_list = ['Joe','Phil','Frank','Daniel']
name_choice = random.choice(name_list)
name_string = '======| {0} |======'.format(name_choice)
print('{0:.16}'.format(name_string))

======| Phil |==  # Result
====| Phil |==== # What I want
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `| {0} |` to the formatting in [simon.sim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38471007/1248974) produces the OP's desired ouput shown in the question:

```
import random

def extra_format(text):
    return '{0:=^16}'.format(text)

name_list = ['Joe','Phil','Frank','Daniel']
name_choice = random.choice(name_list)
print(extra_format('| {0} |'.format(name_choice))) # ====| Phil |==== # What I want
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that will return your desired output:

```
def heading(text):
    return '{0:=^16}'.format(text)
heading(name_choice)
```

Please note that if one of the names in the list is longer than 16 characters, this function will return the entire name, without `=` signs.

Comment: This answer works really well but the output `======Phil======` is missing the space and `|` characters surrounding the name_choice like the OP specified in the question `====| Phil |==== # What I want`

Answer (score 0):

You should change`print('{0:.16}'.format(name_string))` to `print('{0:16}'.format(name_string))`,then it will work.

Comment: No, the width is a *minimum*. The precision defines the maximum.